# Limiting the amount of rows produced by a sql function by the input

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Trying to output sum of the rows that have the lowest total lost sum of money (lost*amount) where the input (quantity) determines the amount of rows that are used, e.g. input of 3 returns the sum of the lowest 3 rows.
Using MariaDB, current code is:

```
DELIMITER ++
CREATE FUNCTION TotalLoss (quantity INT) returns INT
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        M.lost*C.Number AS total,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY M.Lost*C.Number) AS row
    FROM Money M
    JOIN Company C
        ON M.Id = C.MId
)
SELECT SUM(total) FROM cte WHERE row = quantity;
DELIMITER ;

TABLE Money (Id, lost) has values (1, 10), (2,40), (3,90), (4,100)
Table Company (MId, Number) has values (3, 4), (1,2), (5, 1), (4,1)
```

Given the input 2, output would be 220

Since the lowest two are (10*2 + 100*2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read correctly, you should be able to just use an inequality comparison of the row number:

```
SELECT SUM(total) FROM cte WHERE row <= quantity;
```

For example, if `quantity` were `3`, the above query would sum the totals from the first three (lowest) rows.

You never mentioned what should happen in the event that two or more totals be tied.  In that case, using a rank function instead of row number might make more sense.

**Edit:**

If you wanted to do the same thing in MySQL, you will have to do more work, because it does not support any built in row number functionality (though it might at a later date).  Towards this end, we can use a session variable to keep track of the row number:

```
SELECT SUM(total)
FROM
(
    SELECT
        (@rn:=@rn + 1) AS rn,
        M.lost*C.Number AS total
    FROM Money M
    INNER JOIN Company C
        ON M.Id = C.MId
    INNER JOIN (@rn:=0) t
    ORDER BY
        total
) t
WHERE
    t.rn <= 3;
```

This should run as a plain query as well inside of a stored procedure.  If you need to do this inside a function, you may need to implement some delicate cursor work, as session variables may not be supported.  The reason they may not be supported is that a function would not return the same value at all times given the same input, due to a possibly changing value of session variables.

Comment: Thanks!  How would I go about achieving the same thing using mysql?

Comment: @J.Doe I'm not sure that this is possible from a MySQL function.  Would a stored procedure or plain query be acceptable to you?

Comment: Afraid it has to be a function

Comment: @J.Doe I'm afraid I don't know how to do this in a MySQL function, but keep checking here because someone else might know.

Comment: Cheers for the help